# Is there a way to get the equivalent of close[timenow] in order to use it in calculations of any bar

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to get the equivalent of close[timenow] in order to use it in calculations of any bar.

One thing that gets me close is:

```
futureClose = security(syminfo.tickerid, "12M", close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

As it will work if I am using it for calculations within 12 months of timenow. But let's say I am acting upon a bar from 2018, I can't figure out how to get the close for timenow.

Comment: You cannot look forward on pine-script. Say you have a chart with 10 bars. The script will start at the first bar and have no clue of what the second bar will do. Then it will go to the 2nd bar which have no clue of what will happen on the 3rd bar... and so on...

Comment: But there are some workarounds/exceptions to see into the future, such as the one I listed above. And timenow is another one.

Comment: They are not workaround, like you said yourself "gets me close" is because there is no guarantees your code will work that way: this is not a pine-script specification to guarantee these workarounds will be consistent across timeframes/assets. Now, if you try to explain your actual overall need, maybe other stable solutions could be designed. Why would you ever need to get future price in your code?

Comment: I would like to plot a forecast for the next year into the future using a single line. And I can get close by starting this plot a year prior and offset it by a year but I would also like to have the plot line up with the close on the last bar.

Comment: I assume you figured out how to offset your plot "one year ahead", cool. But which VALUE you wish to project ? I am sorry I don't get what VALUE you are trying to catch exactly. Since you try to use `security()` in your example, I guess you try to do things within a lower timeframe ? Like for example, you would like to project the last known close of a yearly timeframe into a daily timeframe ? Something like that ??